# Can a macro update a token's sheet?

Tags: roll20

Short story: I want a macro to change the sheet of the token it is using OR a heal macro.

Long story: I am using the bars in the token menu to keep track of a crit system. This system works like this:

- I roll 1d100 each time I attack. If it's X or lower I crit. X>1d100 result=Crit... I attack more the once each time I hit something.
- Now each time I attack X grows by two. Each time * attack X+y*2>:1d100 result=Crit.

I am hoping I can use the small bubbles that pop up on the token (radial menu bubbles), to keep track. Heal macro would change the tokens bars which can be connected to the radial menu bubbles, so that would work as well.

Since macros have ways to take journal information (assuming the token is connected to the journal) and use that information to quickly modify rolls, I was thinking there might be a way to reverse this and have the macros affect the journal entries instead.

Answer (score 4):

In Roll20 macros package up multiple chat commands. If you can't get it to work in the chat box then it won't work in the macro.

The following are [the lists of chat commands](https://wiki.roll20.net/Text_Chat).

I don't see any chat commands that effect the text of the status bars or what layer a token is on.

However Roll20, has at the mentor level, a javascript API. With the API you are able to do the stuff you want to do in your question like shift a selected token to a different layer and change the numbers in the three status bars.

[This is the page that introduces the API](https://wiki.roll20.net/API:Introduction).

Comment: I am using macros and in the macros there are ways to take journal information, assuiming the token is connected to the journal and use that information to quickly modify rolls. This site does not include those setting. Thanks for the API, unfortunatly i am not a mentor and is forced to use macros. I was thinking there might be a way to reverse the effect of macros taking from the journal into the macros/rolls and have the macros affect the journal entires.

Comment: There's no forseeable way to reverse that order.  Unfortunately the Journal acts as a 'drop' , of sorts.  You can take the token from the journal and drop it anywhere you need with macros, numbers, and all the math exactly the same.  Changing the journal would then dynamically change everything else.  It would be too messy unfortunately :(